# Create a C# list of size n and initialize it with 0's

Tags: c#

How can i create a list in C# of variable size and initialize all the elements with 0's?

One way I know is using Enumerable in this way

```
IEnumerable<int> list1 = Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(x => x * 0);
```

Not sure about the time complexity of using this way. Just looking for a better way if any.

Comment: Another way would be `Enumerable.Repeat(0, n);` I'd expect the time complexity to be O(n) either way, once you start enumerating.

Comment: A better approach would be to use an array since you know the length of the list `n` in your case. An array of size `n` would all be initialized to zero.

Comment: You don't need to do math, you can just select the value you want: `IEnumerable<int> list1 = Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(x => 0);`. Also, since `int` values have a default value of `0`, and during an array creation the items are all initialized to their default values, so you can just do `IEnumerable<int> list1 = new int[n];`. Finally, you might want to choose a better name, since `list1` is not a `List`.

Comment: @ivcubr The reason I choose list over array is, some other elements might be added later.

Comment: @JonathonChase and RufusL Thanks for your suggestions. Those really helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Repeat(0, n);
```

will be the memory efficient way but as int has 0 as a default value you can also just do

```
var array = new int[n];
```